Why don't I see items or am able to interact with them? Maybe more issues that just the items?
This is for a class and we are creating a text based game (yes I know this has been asked before but none of the others seem relevant). I have the program half working but I can't pick up items and when I move the right room name displays but if I make an illegal move it just crashes. I'm at a loss and don't have enough spare hair to pull it out in frustration so any help would be appreciated. Code pasted below.
# Lists the rooms on the map


rooms = {
'Cubicle': {'North': 'Copy Room', 'East': 'Coat Room', 'West': 'Break Room'},
'Break Room': {'North': 'Restroom', 'East': 'Cubicle', 'Item': 'Backpack'},
'Restroom': {'South': 'Break Room', 'Item': 'Hat'},
'Copy Room': {'South': 'Cubicle', 'East': 'File Room', 'Item': 'Keys'},
'File Room': {'West': 'Copy Room', 'South': 'Coat Room', 'East': 'Office', 'Item': 'Phone'},
'Coat Room': {'West': 'Cubicle', 'North': 'File Room', 'Item': 'Coat'},
'Office': {'West': 'File Room', 'South': 'Stairwell', 'Item': 'Keycard'},
'Stairwell': {'North': 'Office', 'Villain': 'Boss'},
}

# Keeps track of inventory
inventory = []
nearby_item = ' '

# Keeps track of current room
current_room = 'Cubicle'

while True:

    print(f'You are in the {current_room}\nInventory : {inventory}\n{"-" * 27}')

    # Checks for item in the room
    if 'Item' in rooms[current_room].keys():
        nearby_item = rooms[current_room]["Item"]

    if nearby_item not in inventory:

        # If item name is plural
        if nearby_item[-1] == 's':
            print(f'You see {nearby_item}')

        # If item name is singular
        else:
            print(f'You see a {nearby_item}')

    # Boss encounter
    if 'Boss' in rooms[current_room].keys():

    # Lose condition
    if len(inventory) < 6:
        print(f'You were caught by the Boss and now you will have to work all weekend')
        break

    # Win condition
    else:
        print(f'You were able to sneak by the boss with your hat pulled down low')
        print(f'and with the phone to your ear you looked too busy to interrupt')
        print(f'Congratulations you have escaped the office!')
        break

# User Movement
user_input = input('Enter your move:\n')
next_move = user_input.split(' ')

user_action = next_move[0].title()

# Set variables to generic
item = 'item'
direction = next_move[1].title()

# Determines if a user is trying to move or get an item
if user_action == 'Go':
    current_room = rooms[current_room][direction]
    msg = f"You traveled {direction}."

else:
    msg = f"You can't go that way."

# Picking up an item in room
if user_action == 'Get':
    if item == rooms[current_room]['Item']:
        if item not in inventory:
            inventory.append(rooms[current_room]['Item'])
            msg = f"You have picked up the {item}"
        else:
            msg = f"You already have the {item}"
    else:
        msg = f"Can't find {item}"

elif user_action == "Exit":
    break

else:
    msg = f"Invalid Command"

I have tried using try/except instead of if/else. I have tried renaming and using different variables. I don't know what else I should have tried obviously, I'm new to this.

The code that uses nearby_item should be inside the if 'Item' in rooms[current_room].keys(): block. Otherwise, you'll use the item from the previous room.

Is the indentation in the code snippet correct? Everything after #User movement should be in the loop, but it's not indented. And there's nothing in the #Boss encounter if block.

There are no Boss keys in your rooms. But there's 'Villain': 'Boss', is that what you wanted to check?

If the user enters an invalid direction, current_room = rooms[current_room][direction] will get a NameError error. You need to check that direction is valid first.
